# ContentRendered on ContentPage

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

What is the event that fires in Xamarin Forms when a ContentPage has been rendered?
I would have expected it to use ContentRendered but this does not compile.

Comment: There is no `ContentPage` class in WPF. In Xamarin.Forms, the `ContentPage` class has an `Appearing` event.

Comment: Sorry, I've modified the question to have Xamarin forms

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy Here is the Xamarin.Forms App Lifecycle . May be helpful for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Appearing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.appearing?view=xamarin-forms) event or the [`OnAppearing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Page_OnAppearing) method. Depending on your situation, those are probably the closest thing to what you're looking for. They will be fired/called just as the page is about to appear, and after all of the layout has occurred.